# ¿Como configurar las versiones en las dependencias para no tener problemas de compatibilidad?

Tags: android-studio

Estaba agregando la dependencia correspondiente, en el archivo Gradle/Module:app para trabajar con CardView: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'.
Pero me esta marcando errores el esa linea agregada y en la de app:compat.
Ambas por problema de versiones incompatibles.

Errores: el primero es en la linea de app:compat:

`All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 24.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0 more... (Ctrl+F1)`

el segundo es en la dependencia agregada CardView:

`This support library should not use a different version (24) than the compileSdkVersion (25)`

Bloque de dependencias en el archivo:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

¿Cuál debe ser la forma correcta de colocarlas para evitar ese error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio nos sugiere usar las últimas versiones de las librerías de compatibilidad, y estas deben ser una versión compatible a la definida en:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion ??
    ...
    ...
}
```

en tu caso tienes definida la versión 25 por esa razón obtiene el siguiente mensaje:

> This support library should not use a different version (24) than the
>   compileSdkVersion (25)

en el caso de tus dependencias el problema principal es en la librería del `CardView`, te sugiero cambies a la versión:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

---

Para saber cual es la última versión y configurar, coloca el puntero del mouse sobre la dependencia y te indicará cual es la última versión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, saludos